# NPM Request - How to return the body of the request?

Tags: node.js, request

So I am using the Request NPM module at the moment.

```
request( URL, function (error, response, body) {
    console.log(body);
    var bod = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log(bod.url);
});
```

I want to utilize the bod.url parameter inside an EJS file.

The console.log(bod.url) part works fine and it prints out exactly what I am looking for.

I am looking to do something like the following.

```
request( URL, function (error, response, body) {
    console.log(body);
    var bod = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log(bod.url);
    var bod2 = bod.url;
});


res.render("image",{url:bod2});
```

but it keeps saying that bod2 is undefined.

If I make bod2 a variable outside of the request function then my EJS tempalte renders it correctly.

I know I am missing something fundamental but I cannot see where I am going wrong here.

***Update***

If I do the following it works...but is this bad practice inside of a route?

```
request( URL, function (error, response, body) {
    console.log(body);
    var bod = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log(bod.url);
    var bod2 = bod.url;
    res.render("image",{url:bod2});                                                                                                      
});
```

Comment: If I do the following                                                                         request( URL, function (error, response, body) {
    console.log(body);
    var bod = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log(bod.url);
    var bod2 = bod.url;
res.render("image",{url:bod2});                                                                                                      });  it works a treat...is this a bad way of doing it though...

Comment: no it is not bad. I have posted answer of your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because of Scope of a variable, that is the issue which occurs sometimes.
So either you can use the following code to handle such situations.

```
request( URL, function (error, response, body) {
    console.log(body);
    var bod = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log(bod.url);
    var bod2 = bod.url;
    res.render("image",{url:bod2});
});
```

OR you can just declare bod2 above request block as

```
var bod2;
return new Promise(resolve => {
   request( URL, function (error, response, body) {
      console.log(body);
      var bod = JSON.parse(body);
      console.log(bod.url);
      this.bod2 = bod.url;

   }, function (error, response, body) {
      if(!error)
         resolve(body);
   });
```

Comment: please approve and upvote my answer if it works for you ^_^

Comment: Hi, im trying to do the same thing. I dont seem to get your answer. bod2 assignment hasnt happened at all. Appreciate your help!